# AWK: search one column, print list of matches in second column

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following TAB delimited file:

```
string1 string2 string3 001 string4
string5 string6 string7 002 string8
string9 string10 string11 003 string12
string13 string14 string15 002 string16
```

and I want to use awk to print all items in column 4 and print a list of matches of column 5 next to it
(the number is the identifier)

```
001 string4
002 string8, string16
003 string12
```

my current attempt failed:
`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $4 ~ /^K/ { print $4, print $5 }'`

I also do not know how to implement to print me a list in column 2 of the matches.

Comment: If `002 string8` appears twice in the input, should the output be `002 string8` (i.e. show unique $5 values) or `002 string8, string8` (i.e. show dup $5 values)

Comment: the string should just appear once!

Comment: and is that how the script you accepted behaves? If not, post a followup question. It's good to come up with comprehensive test cases when posting sample input/output.

Comment: ok, checked again, in my file there are no duplicates, so for the example posted, the script works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Awk` as below,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{unique[$4]=(unique[$4] FS $5); next}END{for (i in unique) print i,unique[i]}' file
```

which produces an output as below. Remember this does *not* retain the order, assuming it does not matter though.

```
002     string8 string16
003     string12
001     string4
```

If you are worried bout having comma separated values as in question, do it as

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{unique[$4]=(unique[$4]?(unique[$4]","$5):($5)); next}END{for (i in unique) print i,unique[i]}' file
```

to produce an output as

```
002 string8,string16
003 string12
001 string4
```

The idea is

- Since `Awk` process files one line at a time, hash-map array `unique` is created with `$4` being the index and value being `$5`
- When more than one value of `$5` is present per index, the values are appended to the existing value with a `,` de-limiter added. The ternary operator takes care of that, which works by seeing the array element has a value if so append the new value with `,` or if empty assign the `$5` value directly.
- The `END` clause prints the formed hash-map, key and key-value which will get the value as needed.

Answer (score 0):

@tobi:@try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$4]=A[$4]?A[$4]","$NF:$NF;next} ($4 in A){print $4,A[$4];delete A[$4]}'   Input_file  Input_file
```

Checking FNR==NR(this condition will be true when 1st Input_file will be read), so making an array named A whose index is $4 and concatenating it's value with last column to it's own in first read of Input_file, next will leave all next statement. Then looping through in array A with $4 in it, printing the values.